# Can we use "evaluate" function for other models not included in dismo package?

Tags: r, random-forest, dismo

I'm using several models to predict species occurence probabilities. Some of them are not included in dismo library such as "MARS" and random forests. I want to know if I still can use "evaluate" function of dismo to evaluate those models.  I mean when I run this line :

```
eval_mars_test <- evaluate(p=envtest_p , a=envtest_a,  model= model_mars)
```

It shows no error but how can I confirm that TPR and FPR here are correctly calculated?

Comment: By design, yes, but given the variability in R model implementation, it can be prudent to cross-check.  I could show you how if you edit your question and include a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

In looking at help and the source for `dismo::evaluate` function the model argument will accept any model that has a predict method. You can also just pass the function the estimated probabilities for each class, which makes your application very easy.

```
library(randomForest)
library(dismo)

data(imports85)
dat <- na.omit(imports85[,-2])
y <- ifelse( dat$numOfDoors != "four", "0", "1")   
( rf.mdl <- randomForest(y = as.factor(y), x = dat[-5]) )

rf.pred <- predict(rf.mdl, type="prob")[,2]

evaluate(p = rf.pred[which(y == "1")], 
         a = rf.pred[which(y == "0")])
```

The `dismo::evaluate` function is applying a cross-validation but, it does not look like it is permutated nor N-fold so, I do not see any specific advantage of using this function over other validation approaches (eg., caret, rfUtilties packages). It would see that a valid approach would be to just predict the model(s) and use the estimates in any viable validation function that will allow for model comparision.

In addition, I would not recommend using AUC/ROC as an evaluation statistic, especially in comparing models as, you have no idea of the partial probability distribution effect on the resulting error. The current emerging gold standard in machine learning models is the log loss function as it penalizes across the entire estimated probability distribution and is not thresholded. Here is a quick example using rfUtilities and the above model.

Here are validation statistics from the predicted model with a default threshold for `randomForest.predict` along with the log loss using the observed binominal and estimated probabilities.

```
library(rfUtilities)
 
accuracy(predict(rf.mdl), y)
logLoss(y, predict(rf.mdl, type="prob")[,2])
```

Here we can test probability threshold on validation.

```
    accuracy(ifelse(predict(rf.mdl, type="prob")[,2] >= 0.60, 1, 0),
    y)[c("kappa","PCC","auc")]
    accuracy(ifelse(predict(rf.mdl, type="prob")[,2] >= 0.65, 1, 0),
    y)[c("kappa","PCC","auc")]
    accuracy(ifelse(predict(rf.mdl, type="prob")[,2] >= 0.70, 1, 0),
    y)[c("kappa","PCC","auc")]
```

A word of warning, if you are thinking of model averaging or weighting, please don’t. This approach gained some prominence, for a very short time, before it was pointed out that model errors assume different structures (linear, additive, exponential, etc…) and when combined, these errors take an unknowable form making any previous validation irrelevant and introducing HUGE uncertainty into any averaged estimate. Adding performance weights really confounds the error structure.